# Reasons why simple Token should be upgradeable

Tags: ether, erc-20, contract-upgrading

The question is that the simple organization token is built with basic Open Zeppelin libraries.

It doesn’t have a custom implementation. It’s not a whatever protocol.

Any reasons to make it upgradeable?

Answer (score 0):

In general, there are plenty of opinions for and against upgradability. I would personally recommend the approach of "unless you have very strong reasons to make something upgradable, just don't". Using upgradability brings a lot of issues.

In your case, there are zero reasons to make it upgradable, and lots of reasons why not to make it upgradable.